# Multivariate combinatorial purged cross-validation

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, backtesting, validation

Combinatorial purged cross-validation (CPCV) is a technique for backtesting strategies while purging and embargoing observations in a time series. CPCV improves upon classical k-fold and walk-forward cross-validation because it has an added layer of generating paths that each possesses a unique Sharpe ratio, allowing a strategy's *Sharpe ratio distribution* to be derived, whereas K-fold and walk forward only provided one Sharpe ratio.

My understanding is that cross-validation is a process that *generates* univariate dataset/time series predictions (but of course the input for *fitting* can be multivariate data). Given that CPCV not only groups based on folds, but also groups to produce multiple backtest paths, does this still make it a univariate predictor? If so, how can CPCV be extended to generate multivariate predictions? for example, maybe a matrix whose columns are individual prediction vectors

But even without an answer to extending it to multivariate format, I just want to understand what CPCV means for multivariate time series data, input and output, given its extra layer of paths to predict.